# Who is responsible for installing a not geniun windows?

Tags: windows-7, legal

There are copies of Windows on the Internet for sale by other users who have a legal copy of Windows and now they want to sell their operating system. Because the price is cheaper I am interested in this option.

However, I am afraid if some of those people have illegal copy of Windows and by buying from those people not I only I lose my money but I am worried I get in trouble by authorities.
I want to know if I buy a copy of Windows or if someone install a copy of Windows on my laptop and then later it turns out that the windows has not been activated legally, who is responsible for that?

Will Microsoft or any other organization sue me or will they sue the person who sold me that copy of Windows instead?

For example [Amazon Germany](http://www.amazon.de/Windows-Professional-64-Bit-Lizenz-Multilingual/dp/B00JIO3XEO/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top) has a copy of Windows 7 Professional for 33 euro.

If I buy this and turns out it is not valid, what would happen? Would I be responsible for installing an illegal copy of Windows? Could I get a valid key from Microsoft?

Comment: Saving a few dollars and getting an illegal operating system is just asking for trouble. You have no way of knowing what is in that installation. Vote to close.

Comment: @Xavierjazz. Because someone can legally sell his own OS, I think this is a legitimate question. Specially when the price is either half of the market price or when someone get a copy of Window from a relative or friend.

Comment: You can legal obtain a trial version direct from microsoft, here is 1 example link http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24209.iso  You will be able to use a valid key to active it.  However, making sure you have a legal product key is harder.

Comment: Let's be honest, Microsoft practically don't sue a person (not organization) for using illegal copy of Windows. If it turns out illegal copy, the biggest issue can be deeply hidden backdoor inside it (if you get in ISO image, not just a license key). Such backdoors are very hard to detect (even with best antiviruses). So if you get one, it's recommended to do a full scan of computer and use network monitor to see if there is suspicious activity. If everything is OK, then you are lucky.

Comment: The person who installed it.

Comment: @Ramhound. I did not intend to use pirated version. I am saying that if someone claims that he has a valid key for Windows and I buy it because it would be cheaper, then am I the one who broke the law?
I know that if I buy a stolen car while I did not know it had been stolen, I am not prosecuted. However, in case of digital media I don't know what happens.

Comment: The point is that there are users with legal license who want to sell their own license. They sell it cheaper  otherwise people would buy from Microsoft itself. Some of them might be a cheater. I was wondering if the victim of the fraud would be prosecuted or not.

Comment: @yashar - Only purchase computers where the COA sticker exists.  If its Windows 8 then a sticker without the key itself should exist indicating its genuine.  The simplest solution.  Verify the license is genuine BEFORE you purchase it.

Comment: @Ramhound Here in amazon.de there is one used windows for 32 euro:
http://tinyurl.com/qxqa3f2
How can I check the sticker?

Comment: @yashar - Amazon offers a certain amount of protection.  Check the terms of the purchase.  Personally its not worth the risk to save a couple bucks.

Answer (score 7):

Look, if you buy it from a non-trusted source, nothing can be done. Microsoft won't sue anyone of you. It's up to you to claim a legal action against the person. However, if you bought from a recognized reseller and the Windows gets out be illegal (pirated) *(because Ebay once sold pirated and non-genuine Windows copies)* you should can directly contact Microsoft about it and they would begin a legal crackdown.

Furthermore, you should never buy a used license or buy Windows from an anonymous person. Purchase it from official Microsoft partners.